# Problem with python class

Tags: python

Hi I am new to Python and as a part of my assignment I have written the following class

```
import nltk.stem.api

class BanglaStemmer(nltk.stem.api.StemmerI):

    suffixList = ['\xef\xbb\xbf\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa7\x9f\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xb2\xe0\xa6\xbe\xe0\xa6\xae\n', '\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa7\x9f\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xb2\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\xa8\n', '\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa7\x9f\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xb2\xe0\xa7\x87\n', '\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa7\x9f\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xb2\xe0\xa6\xbf\n', '\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa7\x9f\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xb2\n', '\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa7\x9f\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\xa8\n', '\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa7\x9f\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xb8\n', '\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa7\x9f\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa6\xbf\n', '\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa7\x9f\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa7\x87\n', '\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa7\x9f\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\x9b\n', '\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa7\x9f\xe0\xa7\x8b\n', '\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xb2\xe0\xa6\xbe\xe0\xa6\xae\n', '\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xb2\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\xa8\n', '\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xb2\xe0\xa7\x87\n', '\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xb2\xe0\xa6\xbf\n', '\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xb2\n', '\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\xa8\n', '\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xb8\n', '\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa6\xbf\n', '\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa7\x87\n', '\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\x9b\n', '\xe0\xa6\xa4\xe0\xa7\x87\n', '\xe0\xa6\x9a\xe0\xa7\x8d\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xb2\xe0\xa6\xbe\xe0\xa6\xae\n', '\xe0\xa6\x9a\xe0\xa7\x8d\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xb2\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\xa8\n', '\xe0\xa6\x9a\xe0\xa7\x8d\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xb2\xe0\xa7\x87\n', '\xe0\xa6\x9a\xe0\xa7\x8d\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xb2\xe0\xa6\xbf\n', '\xe0\xa6\x9a\xe0\xa7\x8d\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xb2\n', '\xe0\xa6\x9a\xe0\xa7\x8d\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xb8\n', '\xe0\xa6\x9a\xe0\xa7\x8d\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa6\xbf\n', '\xe0\xa6\x9a\xe0\xa7\x8d\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\xa8\n', '\xe0\xa6\x9a\xe0\xa7\x8d\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa7\x87\n', '\xe0\xa6\x9a\xe0\xa7\x8d\xe0\xa6\x9b\n', '\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xb2\xe0\xa6\xbe\xe0\xa6\xae\n', '\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xb2\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\xa8\n', '\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xb2\xe0\xa7\x87\n', '\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xb2\xe0\xa6\xbf\n', '\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xb2\n', '\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xb8\n', '\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa6\xbf\n', '\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\xa8\n', '\xe0\xa6\x9b\n', '\xe0\xa6\xa4\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xb8\n', '\xe0\xa6\xa4\xe0\xa6\xbe\xe0\xa6\xae\n', '\xe0\xa6\xb2\xe0\xa6\xbe\xe0\xa6\xae\n', '\xe0\xa6\xb2\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\xa8\n', '\xe0\xa6\xa4\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\xa8\n', '\xe0\xa6\xac\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\xa8\n', '\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\xa8\n', '\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xb8\n', '\xe0\xa7\x81\xe0\xa6\xa8\n', '\xe0\xa7\x81\xe0\xa6\x95\n', '\xe0\xa6\xb2\xe0\xa7\x87\n', '\xe0\xa6\xac\xe0\xa7\x87\n', '\xe0\xa6\xb2\xe0\xa6\xbf\n', '\xe0\xa6\xac\xe0\xa6\xbf\n', '\xe0\xa6\xa4\xe0\xa6\xbf\n', '\xe0\xa6\xb2\n', '\xe0\xa6\xa4\n', '\xe0\xa7\x8b\n', '\xe0\xa6\xbf\n', '\xe0\xa7\x87\n', '\xe0\xa7\x8d\n', '\xe0\xa6\x87\n', '\xe0\xa6\xac\n', '\xe0\xa6\xb8\n', '\xe0\xa6\xa8\n', '\xe0\xa6\x95\n', '\xe0\xa6\x93\n', '\xe0\xa7\x9f\n']

    def stem(self,token):
        for suffix in suffixList:
            if token.endswith(suffix):
                return token[:-len(suffix)]

        return token
```

The problem is that when I try to compile run it by creating an instance and calling the `stem()` function with a parameter , it says that the `suffixList` is not defined. Couldn't figure out what's the problem. Is there a different way in which the class variables have to be declared ? please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for suffix in suffixList:
```

should be

```
for suffix in self.suffixList:
```

Unlike a lot of OOP languages, Python requires you to qualify class members inside the class methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `BanglaStemmer.suffixList` or `self.suffixList` to access the variable. Plain `suffixList` would only work on a local (defined in the function) or a global (defined in the module) variable.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, unlike most other languages, you always have to explicitely reference the instance of which you want to access a member (or "attribute" in Python). This instance is always passed as the first parameter to your methods; this is the reason why this first parameter is called `self` by convention.

`suffixList` in your case is a class attribute, i.e. it is shared by all instances of the class (unless redefined). So you access it with `self.suffixList`.